# version control, apt (and Docker)

Tags: version-control, docker, apt

I have a Dockerfile that does:

```
from ubuntu
build_my_package main-branch
apt-get update && apt-get install -y my_package some_third_party_packages
```

The version control for my_package source code is managed by GIT as is the Dockerfile itself.

I tag my current version as JAGUAR_RC1 (release candidate 1), build an image from the Dockerfile and send image.JAGUAR_RC1 to testing.

I get a bug report, make a fix in GIT, create a new image image.JAGUAR_RC2 and send this new image to testing.

**Bad Idea!** QC reports several new bugs that turn out to be caused by a new version of a third-party package that I never intended to update.

So what is the right way?

Comment: Why can you not store the docker images? If you want to make a change, then you can build from this image.

Comment: Based on the comments received, perhaps the answer is:

1) use git for versions of your source code
2) use a docker registry for versions of your images
3) a **release** *version1* is the source code tagged *version1* together with the images tagged *version1*
4) jenkins needs to know how to build and deploy both together
<br>
Is this the right idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have that backwards (or I misunderstand) but people *create a container to fix and freeze versions* and then keep the container.

Otherwise, you need to nail down *exact versions* which you. Debian has e.g. [snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org). And I work a lot with R too where you can use the archive portion of the [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org) network, and people have written tools to install old version.s